# How to make specific component initial route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just implemented react-router into my app. I have a series of "pages" (components) that I have rendering at different urls:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>    
    <div>
      <Route path='/Home' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/Shop' component={Shop} />
      <Route path='/Contact' component={Contact} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

My issue is that I can't figure out a proper way to make the Home page be the first page the user sees. Right now I have to manually add a `/Home` to my url to view it and that is obviously not preferred.

I tried adding a redirect from `/` that takes you to the home page -

```
<Redirect from="/" to="/Home" />
```

But the issue here is that since `/` is in every single url, so any url I enter redirects to home.

Is there a way to make that more explicit, so that it redirects if `/` is the *only* thing appended to the url? Or is there a better way to accomplish my overall issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you could use `<Route path='/' component={Home} />`

Comment: @FuzzyTree The issue I ran into with that is it then renders `Home` at every other page too, because they all have `/` in the url as well.

Comment: See my answer. Adding exact={true} will fix that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<Route path='/Home' component={Home} />
```

to

```
<Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
```

Now the home page will show only when you are on exactly `/`.

Edit: see the docs here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: Thank you!! This is `exact`ly what I needed ;)